# Warning: vim-7.4.712_1 already installed, it's just not linked

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew, macvim

Disclaimer: Complete Noob

I just started using OS X for the first time. Decided to start using vim. I installed vim with YouCompleteMe. However, when I realized I did not have the appropriate version to use the plug in, I believe I reinstalled on top of the existing installation which I read afterwards was bad. I then tried installing through brew by using the command

```
brew install vim --override-system-vi
```

Now I get the error

```
 Warning: vim-7.4.712_1 already installed, it's just not linked
```

All I want to do is install vim 7.4 so I can install YouCompleteMe.

When I run the vim command I get all this junk

```
Error detected while processing /Users/raulalan/.vimrc:
line   50:
E117: Unknown function: vundel#rc
line   59:
E492: Not an editor command: ^D # This means Ctrl+D
YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim 7.3.584+
```

Is this due to installing on top of the existing directory without using the -override-system-vi flag. Help is super appreciated since I feel completely lost using these new environments.

Answer (score 3):

Brew is telling you that you installed vim, but for some reason it can't be linked. This is usually because there are other files around that brew doesn't know about, and doesn't want to delete.

To link vim, run `brew link vim`. Brew may refuse to link, and instead tell you that linking would delete some files. In that case, use `brew link vim --overwrite`.